# How to replace string in mongodb collection with arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

My `FoodRecord` records contains something like this:

```
"_modifierRecords" : [
    "com.domain.data.REM.FoodModifierRecord:57919e6930049c15986e7c05"
    "com.domain.data.REM.FoodModifierRecord:57919e6930049c15986e7c06"
], 
"_discountModifierRecords" : [

], 
"_salesRecord" : "com.domain.data.REM.SalesRecord:57919e6930049c15986e7c01"
```

I need to replace `com.domain.data.REM.` to just `com.domain.data.` if they exists in the 3 fields above.

This is what I have so far but I'm having problems:

```
var operations = [];
db.FoodRecord.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var operation = {
        updateOne: { 
            filter: { '_id': doc._id }, 
            update: { 
                '$set': { '_salesRecord': doc._salesRecord.replace('com.domain.data.REM.SalesRecord:', 'com.domain.data.SalesRecord:'),
                  '_modifierRecords.$' : doc._modifierRecords.$.replace('com.domain.data.REM.FoodModifierRecord:', 'com.domain.data.FoodModifierRecord:') }
            }
        }
    };
    operations.push(operation);
})

operations.push({ 
    ordered: true, 
    writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 } 
})

db.FoodRecord.bulkWrite(operations, { ordered : false });
```

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: Currently my db version is 3.2.8 I believe

Answer (score 0):

That solution seems to work, but that's probably not the optimal one.

```
db.FoodRecord.find(/* your query */).forEach(function(e,i){
    var newArr = [];
    e._salesRecord.forEach(function(e,i) {
         newArr.push(e.replace('REM.SalesRecord','SalesRecord'));
    });
    e._salesRecord = newArr;
    newArr = [];
    e._modifierRecords.forEach(function(e,i) {
         newArr.push(e.replace('REM.FoodModifierRecord','FoodModifierRecord'));
    });
    e._modifierRecords = newArr;
    db.FoodRecord.save(e);
});
```